# On main page link image to post page, on post page link it to it's own image?

Tags: links

I'm using a lightbox plugin that blows the image up to it's own window when an image is clicked. I want this behavior to ONLY happen when the image is clicked on from it's POST page. When the same image is clicked from the MAIN (home) page I want the user to be navigated to the POST page.

**So the flow would be:**

**1.** User clicks the image on main page (or any other page than it's own post page for that matter) ...
**2.** That takes them to the post page the image is on ...
**3.** The user clicks the image on it's *own* post page ...
**4.** The image pops up in it's lightbox frame.

I'm completely new to WordPress, can anyone help me with this?

thanks!

Comment: Just change the code. :) There isn’t much more to say, because we don’t how your code looks like. Please improve your question, make sure we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: So the plugin isn't quite working the way you want it to, no big surprise. Have you thoroughly gone over the plugin's reading material? forums? Chances are there's a way to do this and it has already been explained. If not, chances are there's a better plugin that will have these basic options laid out.